# Interactions (MIMO systems)

Tags: control-theory

[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NOkZ.jpg)

According to the page above, an LTI MIMO system could be affected by many interactions.
I have two questions about this page:

1. Is it described the system using differential equations (as well as it would be done with a spring-mass system)?
2. Why does it say that the MIMO system is described by differential equations if the set of equations (8.11) is in the complex variable 's'? I guess here it was applied a Laplace transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the system is described with differential equations, i.e:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A x + B u \\
y &= C x + D u
\end{align}
$$

MIMO for the LTI system just mean that $B$ has $\geq 2$ columns (multiple inputs) and $C$ has $\geq 2$ rows (multiple outputs). And yes the 8.11 equation is the Laplace transformation.

For example:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1 \\0&-1&0 \\-5&-10&-15
\end{pmatrix},B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},C =\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1  \end{pmatrix},D=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} y_1(s)\\y_2(s)\\y_3(s) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{-10}{s^3 + 16 s^2 + 20 s + 5} & \frac{1}{s^2 + 15 s + 5} \\ 
\frac{1}{s + 1}  & 0  \\
\frac{-10s}{s^3 + 16 s^2 + 20 s + 5} & \frac{s}{s^2 + 15 s + 5} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_1(s) \\ u_2(s) \end{pmatrix}
$$

You can see that $u_1$ influences all outputs but $u_2$ influences only $y_1$ and $y_3$ but not $y_2$.

Comment: You are using the state space representation. I am not familiar with that. My professor used to draw the model (ex spring-mass model) and then he wrote the differential equations. Then it was applied the Laplace transformation. Anyway my aim was to understand if it is possible for a MIMO system to have interactions even if it is LTI. I guess this page states that even if a MIMO system is LTI, it Is possible to have interactions. Right?

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi Yes, this is correct. You can see the interaction in the figure 8.9.